select2 blade component and livewire3 - setting new selected value
There are many topics regarding livewire and select2. I have read many of them. I watched videos in languages I don't even speak. I just cannot get one thing working - dynamically changing the selected value in the backend (livewire) and show it correctly in blade.
I have a select2 blade component, which basically works.
@props(['id', 'label' => '')

<div class="mb-5">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column form-floating" wire:ignore id="parent_{{ $id }}">
        <select {{ $attributes }} id="{{ $id }}" class="form-select"
            @error($attributes->whereStartsWith('wire:model')->first())
                {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'is-invalid form-select ']) }}
            @else
                {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'form-select ']) }}
            @enderror
            >

            {{ $slot }}

        </select>
        <label>
            <span>{{ $label }}</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    @error($attributes->whereStartsWith('wire:model')->first())
        <div class="text-danger ms-3">Error: {{ $message }}</div>
    @enderror
</div>

@push('scripts')
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#{{ $id }}').select2({
                dropdownParent: $('#parent_{{ $id }}'),
                placeholder: '{{ $placeholder }}',
            }).on('change', function() {
                @this.set('{{ $attributes->whereStartsWith('wire:model')->first() }}', $(this).val());
            })
        })
    </script>
@endpush

I can use it like this in blade
<x-forms.select2-livewire id="supplier" required
    wire:model="supplierForm.id" label="Supplier">
    <option>Choose ...</option>
    @foreach ($suppliers as $supplier)
        <option value="{{ $supplier->id }}">{{ $supplier->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</x-forms.select2-livewire>

this works great exept for one thing: if I change the selected value in the backend, the select2 shows always the first option.
In the DOM it is that element of the select2:
<span class="selection">...</span>

If i click it, the select2 shows the selected value with a checkmark, so it is working "behind the scenes and the select input has the correct value.
I have tried using alpine, I have tried emiting an event and recreate the select2, but nothing worked ...
I tried setting the elements value as value and trigger change on the select - no effekt.
The component works fine on the first boot - it is really only that changeing the value after the first boot that drives me crazy. Has anyone figured this out?
